# How to create object array in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I need to know how to create object array in rails and how to add elements in to that.

I'm new to ruby on rails and this could be some sort of silly question but I can't find exact answer for that. So can please give some expert ideas about this

Comment: What are you using to learn Ruby? This should have been covered in the first chapter or so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since everything is an object in Ruby (including numbers and strings) any array you create is an object array that has no limits on the types of objects it can hold. There are no *arrays of integers*, or *arrays of widgets* in Ruby. Arrays are just arrays.

```
my_array = [24, :a_symbol, 'a string', Object.new, [1,2,3]]
```

As you can see, an array can contain anything, even another array.

Answer (score 20):

All you need is an array:

```
objArray = []
# or, if you want to be verbose
objArray = Array.new
```

To push, `push` or use `<<`:

```
objArray.push 17
>>> [17]

objArray << 4
>>> [17, 4]
```

You can use any object you like, it doesn't have to be of a particular type.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the situation, I like this construct to initialize an array.

```
# Create a new array of 10 new objects
Array.new(10) { Object.new }
#=> [#<Object:0x007fd2709e9310>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e92e8>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e92c0>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e9298>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e9270>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e9248>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e9220>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e91f8>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e91d0>, #<Object:0x007fd2709e91a8>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you need to create array of words next construction could be used to avoid usage of quotes:

```
array = %w[first second third]
```

or

```
array = %w(first second third)
```